# Ruby: Update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently getting this error when running `Shop.last.destroy` and I can't figure out why:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "credit_changes" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_16918229d0" on table "sms_historicals" (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
```

And this is a Postgres DB

My models look like this:

```
class SmsHistorical < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :credit_change, optional: true
  belongs_to :notification_setting, optional: true
end

class CreditChange < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :credit
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :sms_historicals
  has_one :email_historicals
end
```

And then the migrations to create these tables are these:

```
create_table :credit_changes, if_not_exists: true do |t|
  t.integer "credit_id"
  t.text "credit_notes"
  t.decimal "credit_amount_changed", precision: 4, scale: 2, default: 0.0
  t.datetime "date"
  t.string "transaction_type"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

class CreateSmsHistoricals < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :sms_historicals, if_not_exists: true do |t|
      t.string :phone_number
      t.text :message
      t.references :customer, null: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.references :credit_change, null: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.references :notification_setting, null: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `has_one :sms_historicals, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: this comment fixed the issue.. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to :credit_change` is a FK between Sms and Credit tables. And Credit ID is stored in the Sms table. When you try to delete Credit, you also need to clear data in the Sms table. For example

```
class CreditChange < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :sms_historicals, dependent: :nullify
end
```

I choose `:nullify` here because you set `belongs_to :credit_change` on the Sms table as optional. But can be something else: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one